# How to do the stroke for "bowl"?

Tags: kanji, stroke-order

When writing the Kanji 丼 (bowl), do I start with the horizontal lines first or the vertical lines?

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%23kanji%20%E4%B8%BC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This incredibly nifty website should help!.https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%BC%20%23kanji